# Use Reselect with ownProps for best practice?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reselect

I want select stream info from my redux state. It's work but I very confuse when I try select deep state from my redux state. I want select (`state.livestream.subscribeLiveStream[postID].des`, `state.livestream.subscribeLiveStream[postID].views`, ...) with `postID` from `ownProps`. Here is my code. My question

1. Is the code in selector and component good ?
2. If it's not, please explain for me why.

Thank you for your help.
Here is what I have

**reducer**

```
state = {
  livestream: {
    subscribeLiveStream: {
      'a': {
        des: 'My stream a',
        views: 0,
        status: 0,
      },
      'b': {
        des: 'My stream b',
        views: 0,
        status: 0,
      }
      // 'a', 'b' is ID
    }
  },
  // other
}
```

**Selector**

```
const livestreamSelector = state => state.livestream;

/* select subscribeLiveStream */
export const selectSubLiveStream = createSelector(
  livestreamSelector,
  livestream => livestream.subscribeLiveStream
);

/* select subscribeLiveStream info */
const getPostID = (_, postID) => postID;
export const makeSelectSubLiveStreamViews = () => createSelector(
  [selectSubLiveStream, getPostID],
  (subLiveStream, postID) => subLiveStream[postID]?.views || 0
);
```

**Using in component:**

```
const LiveStream = ({ postID }) => {
  const selectSubLiveStreamViews = useMemo(makeSelectSubLiveStreamViews, []);
  const views = useSelector(state =>
    selectSubLiveStreamViews(state, postID)
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <p>My stream views: {views}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Code appears fine to me. You say it works. What is the concern here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the argument postID as the first argument:

```
//pass in postId and return a selector function
export const makeSelectSubLiveStreamViews = (postId) => createSelector(
  [selectSubLiveStream],
  (subLiveStream) => subLiveStream[postID]?.views || 0
);
```

In your component:

```
//you need to recreate the selector function when postId chages
//  or you'll get the wrong data
const selectSubLiveStreamViews = useMemo(
  ()=>makeSelectSubLiveStreamViews(postId), [postId]
);
//no need to pass postId again, code looks a little cleaner
const views = useSelector(selectSubLiveStreamViews);
```

[Here](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors) are some examples how I use reselect with React-redux.

Comment: thanks for your help, It's good, but I have a question, I want keep file Selector, when I use in component, I write:
`const selectSubLiveStreamViews = useMemo(() => makeSelectSubLiveStreamViews,[postId]);
const views = useSelector(state => selectSubLiveStreamViews(state, postID));`

It's wrong or it's similar your comment ??? Thank you.
because `makeSelectSubLiveStreamViews` change when `postId` change

Comment: @PhátNguyễn I guess your code is more or less the same but since you use memo anyway you can pass postId first. The main problem with the code in your question is that postId dependency was missing in the useMemo. I just like the syntax I use better.